# Forge viewer: how to isolate custom objects?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We use custom objects to visualize ifc space data (mostly rooms). As a guidance, we used this very helpful [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer). After drawing the objects, we would also like to select the custom objects from outside and isolate them in the viewer. As the tutorial suggests, we change the model builder's *changeFragmentsDbId* function to set DbIds that do not exist yet and therefor do not overlap with already existing DbIds. One approach is to use the negative space [-1, -2, -3...] for our custom objects DbIds like this:

```
const roomFragId = this.modelBuilder.addFragment(roomGeometryId, materialName, transform);
this.modelBuilder.changeFragmentsDbId(roomFragId, -roomFragId);
```

Another one is to find the maximum DbId (eg. 4905) and use numbers higher than this maximum DbId for our custom objects DbIds (eg. [4906, 4907, 4908...]):

```
const roomFragId = this.modelBuilder.addFragment(roomGeometryId, materialName, transform);
this.modelBuilder.changeFragmentsDbId(roomFragId, maxDbId + roomFragId);
```

However, when we try to isolate a custom drawn object (`viewer.isolate(-1)` or `viewer.isolate(4906)`), the viewer kind of refreshs itself, but no object gets isolated...
Thus, we would like to know how we can isolate custom objects?

The other way, when we select the object in the viewer works for the negative space approach => we get the DbId (eg. -1) in the aggregate selection event.

Thank you for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To isolate or select custom objects created by the `SceneBuilder` ext, you need to pass `model` object to `Viewer3D#isolate` / `Viewer3D#select` like the below. Otherwise, `viewer` will use `viewer.model` instead.

```js
viewer.isolate( [4906, 4907, 4908...], this.modelBuilder.model )

viewer.select( [4906, 4907, 4908...], this.modelBuilder.model )
```